# if degree of $g(x)=4$, degree of $q(x)=3$ and degree of $r(x)=2$, then find the degree of $p(x)$.

Tags: polynomials

Hint= $p(x)=g(x)*q(x)+r(x)$.
Can I use the following equation for finding degree of polynomial,degree of $p(x)=$ degree of $[g(x)*q(x)]$. If that's the case, what will happen to remainder?

Comment: Well, in general $p(x)=g(x)q(x) + r(x)$ only implies $deg(p) \leq deg(gq)$. But it looks like you want to look at the euclidean algorithm, where you know that $deg(r) < deg(q)$ (or $deg(g)$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can simply apply $deg(p(x))=deg(g(x))\times (q(x))$

And your question,, "what will happen to remainder"

You should remember that remainder are added in the product of $q(x) $ and $g(x)$ and addition does not effect degree of polynomial if $$deg(r(x))\lt deg(q(x))\times (g(x))$$ which is obvious and basic

Comment: You probably mean $deg(p(x))=deg(g(x)\times q(x))$...

Comment: Yes I do @5xum, thanks to pointing out